# How to add padding in drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have custom `EditText` drawable:

**edit_text_selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_background_on" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_background_off" />

</selector>
```

**edit_text_background_on**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/main_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="1.5dp"
        android:left="1.5dp"
        android:right="1.5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/background_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item 
        android:bottom="5.0dp" >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/background_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**edit_text_background_off**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/edittext_off_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="1.5dp"
        android:left="1.5dp"
        android:right="1.5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/background_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="5.0dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/background_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I want to have padding in EditText so that the text is not in the most left position of EditText.

Tried to use this but doesn't work.

```
<inset android:insetLeft="6dip"/>
```

How can I add padding in EditText drawable? I don't want to put it in every EditText in my XML layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this .. Hope it will help. This is the logic . you need to customize it.
This is main Layout where you can add `edittext`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#eee">

    <!-- Input Group -->
    <EditText style="@style/Widget.Group.Top" />
    <EditText style="@style/Widget.Group" />
    <EditText style="@style/Widget.Group.Bottom" />

    <!-- Single item -->
    <EditText style="@style/Widget.Group.Single" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and add some style in you style file like this

```
<style name="Widget.Group" parent="@android:style/Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">46dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">-1dp</item> <!-- Ensures we don't get a 2 dp top stroke -->
        <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
        <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_input_group</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Group.Top">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
        <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_input_group_top</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Group.Bottom">

        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">20dp</item>
        <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_input_group_bottom</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Group.Single" parent="Widget.Group.Top">
        <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_input_group_single</item>-->
    </style>
```

For more details click [here](http://ryanharter.com/blog/2013/02/05/taking-advantage-of-android-styles/) .

Answer (score 0):

For adding the padding in EditText,you need to create the custom editText, override the onLayout() method and set the padding in that method such as

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText
{
  public CustomEditText(Context context) 
  {
     super(context);
  }

  public CustomEditText(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) 
  {
     super(context, attrs);
  }

  public CustomEditText(Context context,AttributeSet  attrs, int defStyle) 
   {
     super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    // set the padding here
    this.setPadding(20,20,20, 20);
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}
}
```